# Missing template for render user/new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionview

I have a problem when trying to render a controller action. Following the documentation I should be able to use:

```
render 'user/new' or
render template: 'user/new' or
render :action => "new", :controller => "users"
```

Although I get a template missing exception and I'm not shure, why. Using a form for works, but it's stupid to copy exactly the same form.

I'm pretty messed, so I'm shurely missing something, but I don't get it.
Any hints?

EDIT: I'm calling from the GroupsController where I want to render the new-user-form. Did a test with only scaffolded models and I get the same error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (
Missing partial users/new with {:locale=>[:de], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/rob/Development/projects/test/app/views"
* "/Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/oembed_provider_engine-0.2.0/app/views"
* "/Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/views"
):
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get? And also where do you use render? Is it in the User controller?

Comment: Did you make sure to specify the controller route you want in your routes.rb file?

Comment: Yes, sir. pretty standard ressources users and also nested routes for the group-controller I'm calling from.

Answer (score 0):

Partial templates' filename always begins with an underscore. So you need a "_new.html.erb" file in your "user" view to render.

If I'm not mistaken, the default scaffolding creates a "_form.html.erb" for each model to render it in new and edit actions both. You can just render that instead of the whole "new" view.

Comment: Regarding to the documentation it should be possible to render a controller action and by default should use the existing template. Of course I don't want to bypass the already existing actions.

If using a partial it is, that's right, necessary, that you name it with a underscore at the beginning...